# how to implement on error goto next on API response in C#

Tags: c#

I have list of ID's and i am looping through each of these ID's to get the details.
In few cases, the API call is failing. So i want to skip the failed API call and want to proceed with next ID API call; similar to on error goto next.

```
foreach (var item in ID)
{
    try
    {
        List<string> resultList = new List<string>();
        url = string.Format(HttpContext.Current.Session["url"].ToString() + 
              ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["propertyURL"].ToString(),
              HttpContext.Current.Session["ObjectID"].ToString(), item);
        var request1 = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request1.Headers["X-Authentication"] = HttpContext.Current.Session["vaultToken"].ToString();
        request1.Method = "GET";
        request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

        //// Get the response.
        var response1 = request1.GetResponse();
        var deserializer1 = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(PropertyValue[]));
        var result1 = (PropertyValue[])deserializer1.ReadObject(response1.GetResponseStream());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

What is the possible solution so that even if the API call fails the foreach loops goes for next ID API call.

Comment: That empty catch block will haunt you in future!

Comment: To amplify what @LasithaPetthawadu said - you can log the failed call in the catch block.  The loop will continue since the try catch is inside your foreach. I.e., you don't have to implement anything.

Comment: What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you just need to move your `resultList` outside the loop. Everything else looks fine...

```
List<string> resultList = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in ID)
{
   try
   {
         // Your Call Here

         // Add Result to resultList here
   }
   catch
   {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is more clear.

```
Dictionary<int, string> resultList = new Dictionary<int, string>();

foreach (var item in ID)
{
   resultList.Add(item,string.Empty);
   try
   {
         // Your Call Here

         // Add Result to resultList here

       var apiCallResult = apiCall(item);
       resultList[item] = apiCallResult;
   }
   catch
   {
   }
}
```

You can query the dictionary for `ID`s that don't have a result.